# Python: alter some matrix values according to a criteria without FOR cycles

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I've been programming in C language for several years, but I'm newbie for Python, so my apologies in advance for my doubt below. I already researched for this in the internet, unsuccessfully.

I got an enormous dataset which has several columns. There are three specific columns that I need to work with. Let's call them DATA, CRITERIA1 and CRITERIA2. I have them each one as numpy ndarray.

The elements in both CRITERIA are integers; shape = (777777,) and type = int32
The elements in DATA are matrices of complex numbers; shape = (3,5,777777) and type = complex128

I call the dimension 777777 as "row-number".

For all the rows that fulfill:

```
((5<CRITERIA1<9) && (CRITERIA2!=7))
```

the matrices elements for corresponding rows must be multiplied by (3,2i).

I can easily do it with FOR cycles and IFs.

However, I was told that Python has the power to do it at once, without FORs and IFs. Is it true?? How???

Greetings!

Comment: No, python does not have this magic power... Using the numpy library, `for loops` are abstracted at the C level (C programming language with which the library is written), but the execution still requires iterating over the values, even if it is hidden to the user. For instance, if `x` and `y` are numpy arrays, you can write `x + y` in python to sum the elements pairwise, however, at the numpy implementation level, there is a for loop that iterates over the arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `np.where()`:

```
import numpy as np

c1 = np.arange(10) # array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
c2 = np.arange(10)+1 # array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
pos = np.where((c1>5) & (c1<9) & (c2!=7))
c1 = c1.astype('complex')
c1[pos] *= np.array([3+2j])
# array([ 0. +0.j,  1. +0.j,  2. +0.j,  3. +0.j,  4. +0.j,  5. +0.j,  6. +0.j, 21.+14.j, 24.+16.j,  9. +0.j])
```